# Concatenating Boolean to DataFrames sqlQuery str

Tags: python, dataframe, isqlquery

I am attempting to query the weather database for building decision trees. In it there are 14 instances and I am making new dataframes based on the intend subset that I want to query e.g -->

```
   new_data = data.query("'rainy' in Outlook")
```

will produce a new dataframe with 5 instances.

```
 ID                                    
 D    rainy  mild     high  False   yes
 E    rainy  cool   normal  False   yes
 F    rainy  cool   normal   True    no
 J    rainy  mild   normal  False   yes
 N    rainy  mild     high   True    no
```

To make my program more dynamic I am iterating through the datasets with parsed headers which look like this

```
    new_data = data.query("'rainy' in " + column_names[0])
```

Where column_names[0] is equal to Outlook. This is working fine , but the issue I am having is when I come to Windy which is a boolean. My question is how do I parse a boolean to a string to make a df query ? At the moment my code reads like this

```
      new_data = data.query("'" + False + "' in Windy")
```

but the error I am getting is 
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'bool' objects
I have tried many variations on the concatenation but have yet to find the correct format , if anyone else has experienced the same problem some insight would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you simply tried the following?

```
new_data = data.query("'" + str(False) + "' in Windy")
```

Comment: I hadn't , but it wont work because then you are making a comparison between a boolean and a string and it will designate them incompatible. It would avoid the compiling error though , just not solve the problem :)

Comment: @Steve can you check it as an integer? 1/0 = True/False?

Comment: Afraid not , as soon as you parse the integer to the query string it becomes just a string and prefixing it with a case bool(1) only throws up the initial compiling error.